# Strange behavior of CanExecuteChanged event

Tags: wpf, command, state

I found a strange behavior, in a custom implementation of `ICommand` interface I have `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method that can be invoked from outside and cause to invoke and reevalute the `CanExecute` method and change the state of the command (and button):

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
  if (_canExecuteChanged != null)
    _canExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

However when the event was implemented as property:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
```

it did not work and `CanExecuteChanged` was `null`.

After changing it to

```
private EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
  add { _canExecuteChanged += value; }
  remove { _canExecuteChanged -= value; }
}
```

it works.

The command is bound to a button `Command` property.

Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the property syntax, you need to use `CanExecuteChanged` in your method:

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Additionally, you should delete `_canExecuteChanged` from your class, because it will not be used.

BTW: The following implementation of `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is better, because it isn't prone to race conditions:

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: There is no possibility for race conditions in WPF Control events anyway. Every event should be triggered and subscribed / unsubscribed in Dispatcher thread anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. After lot of root cause analysis found i have initialized the MainpageData Context twice in the MainPage.xaml page. The second initialization was by accident inside a Grid on the page. Please check for these kind of errors because of which CanExecuteChanged event may not intialize properly